# Replacing existing file content in onedrive by id (using onedrive api) is replacing with empty size file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

following this api doc https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/api/driveitem_put_content?view=odsp-graph-online

Here is the code, have tried every possible thing to pass in the body, here, req.file.buffer is imageBuffer

```
    const { Readable } = require("stream");
    
    const { data } = await axios({
      method: "put",
      url: `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/items/${fileId}/content`,
      headers: {
        Authorization: "bearer " + req.user.auth.accessToken,
        "Content-Type": "application/pdf",
      },
      responseType: "json",
      body: Readable.from(req.file.buffer.toString()),
    });
```

Comment: Not getting, Whats the error/issue here?

Answer (score 0):

`body` expects a `Buffer`, a `Blob`, a `File`, `FormData` or a `String`. I am not sure about your `imageBuffer`. If it is [this](https://github.com/mattdesl/imagebuffer), you should do

```
body: Buffer.from(req.file.buffer.uint8.content)
```

Also, in your `Authorization` header it should be `Bearer` , not `bearer` , although I don't expect that this is the main cause of the problem.